# why doesnt ubuntu 13.04 prompt me for a password after suspend?

Tags: password, prompt

I am on 13.04 and waking from suspend takes me straight to desktop without a password prompt even though it is set to ask for a password in the brightness and lock settings.

Also I recently tried to lock my computer,going to the power menu in the top right corner and hitting lock,it does not do anything,I am still on the desktop..(just tried crtl alt l to lock,it does work) but not the way i did it though,but that is not important to me ,I need the password prompt after suspend..

Password prompts works only when booted from a shutdown...

Comment: On Brightness & Lock > Lock = ON ...try with it

Comment: What DE do you use? The options differ.

Comment: the lock is on,if u read back in my first post

Comment: Could you upload an screenshoot of your *Brightness & Lock* menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install gnome-screensaver

`sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver`

Comment: No, don't use gnome-screensaver, use xScreenSaver instead. It's better, more used, and older (has more bugs taken care of).

Comment: nice thanks it works,I knew it was something ive installed recently,and one of them was cinnamon,when i installed the gnome-screensaver,it removed the cinnamon one..thanks

Comment: Haa... thank you very much. Damned Cinnamon screensaver!

Answer (score 5):

On ubuntu 13.10, macbookair 5.2, gnome-shell 3.8 I've had the same issue.

These have been the system settings:

- `gnome-control-center` > brightness & lock > *lock* on and *require password when waking from suspend* enabled
- `dconf-editor` > *org/gnome/desktop/lockdown/[disable-lock-screen](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=85912#p517372)* disabled
- `dconf-editor` > *org/gnome/desktop/screensaver/lock-enabled* enabled
- `dconf-editor` > *org/gnome/desktop/screensaver/ubuntu-lock-on-suspend* enabled

This had no effect/didn't give any clues:

- `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gnome-screensaver`
- `sudo apt-get install libnss-myhostname` because of `dmesg` error "*[systemd-hostnamed[11869]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. [...]](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1185596)*" which was the only clue there

**This made my day:**

- switching all the above mentioned keys in `dconf-editor` twice

So why? dconf bug? Or a combination of libnss-myhostname/gnome-screensaver/dconf? ... Didn't (want to) reproduce the problem and solution.

---

**Edit:**

After a reboot, the non-locking behavior showed up again. I found out that after locking the screen either by keyboard shortcut (set via `gnome-control-center`) or by console (`gnome-screensaver-command -l`) the locking was restored. So adding `gnome-screensaver &` to [startup applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login) solved the problem. Check `ps -A | grep gnome-screen` if gnome-screensaver is running.

Comment: the odd thing with that is, `gnome-screensaver` should be in the startup applications *by default* with Gnome.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 13.10 and Gnome 3.8. Found the solution in [this post](http://zeroset.mnim.org/2013/10/31/ubuntu-13-10-saucy-how-to-fix-missing-lock-screen-in-gnome-3/).

Gnome 3.8 no longer uses `gnome-screensaver`, but relies on `gdm` for screensaver functionalities, so you should install and use that instead of `lightdm`:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

and select GDM when prompted. If GDM is already installed:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

Comment: You may need to use `gdm3` instead.